# How to find irreducible factors of the polynomial $p(x) = x^5 -1$ over integers modulo $5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Ok so I'm trying to answer this question.  I've started by using the factor theorem to determine that $\ p(x) = x^5 -1 =(x-1)(x^4 + x^3 +x^2 +x +1)\ $
I have no idea what to do next to reduce this polynomial over the modulo 5 field. 
If someone could provide me with the next steps in an algorithmic form, that would be excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that in $\mathbb Z_5$ that $x^5 = x$?  We can conclude and verify by simple calculations that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x+1=1$ if $x=0, 2,3,4$ and is equal to $0$ if $x = 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic

Comment: I was not but that makes so much sense. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, $x^5-1=(x-1)^5$.

Comment: Yes this exactly. Thank you so much but how did you reach this?

Comment: It's called "Freshman's Dream". Given integers $a,b$ and a prime $p$, expand $$(a+b)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p{p\choose k}a^kb^{p-k}$$ using the binomial theorem. Note that for $1\leq k\leq p-1$, $p|{p\choose k}$. Therefore, in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you have $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$.

Comment: Also by Eulers theorem.  $x^5 = x$ so $x^5 -1= x-1=(x-1)^5$.